# Python cannot load file

Tags: python, file

I am learning Python and would be grateful for your advice on this problem.

I have written a program with some functions in it to implement a simple word search game (see code below). I was given a driver program which only works if my program has been correctly implemented. I tested all my functions with examples and they seemed to work correctly but when I run the driver program I get this error message

```
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<name>/Documents/a3_driver.py", line 88, in <module>
    words = a3.read_words(words_file)
  File "/Users/<name>/Documents/a3.py", line 266, in read_words
    fh = open(words_file)
TypeError: invalid file: None
```

I believe it relates to my second last function called *read_words*, but I cannot seem to work out the problem. Any feedback would be extremely appreciated, I have included the code for this function below (I've also included the last function as well called read_board as this is very similar and also reads a txt file, just in case i've made the same mistake twice). Thank you in advance

the driver program for the game can be downloaded from the bottom of this page:
http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/programming1/a3/a3.html

### The *read_words* function creates a words list made up of the words from a file.

```
def read_words(words_file):
    """ (file open for reading) -> list of str

    Return a list of all words (with newlines removed) from open file
    words_file.

    # A simple .txt file used in this function simply contains the 4 words below, each printed on a new line 
    CRUNCHY
    COWS
    EAT
    GRASS

    >>> read_words('wordlist1.txt')
    ['CRUNCHY', 'COWS', 'EAT', 'GRASS']

    Precondition: Each line of the file contains a word in uppercase characters
    from the standard English alphabet.
    """

    fh = open(words_file)

    lst = []

    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip()
        for i in line.split():
            lst.append(i)

    return lst
    #print (lst)

    fh.close()
```

### The *read_board* function creates a board made up of the rows of letters from a file.

```
def read_board(board_file):
    """ (txt file) -> list of list of str

    # A simple txt file used in this example contains the following...
    EFJAJCOWSS
    SDGKSRFDFF
    ASRJDUSKLK
    HEANDNDJWA
    ANSDNCNEOP
    PMSNFHHEJE
    JEPQLYNXDL

    >>> read_board('board1.txt')
    [['EFJAJCOWSS'], ['SDGKSRFDFF'], ['ASRJDUSKLK'], ['HEANDNDJWA'], ['ANSDNCNEOP'], ['PMSNFHHEJE'], ['JEPQLYNXDL']]


    Return a board read from open file board_file. The board file will contain
    one row of the board per line. Newlines are not included in the board.
    """

    data = []

    fh = open(board_file)

    for line in fh:
        items = line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t')   # strip new-line characters and split     on column delimiter
        data.append(items)

    return data

    fh.close()
```

Comment: Do you really need to provide all this code in order to ask your question? Isolate the problem next time and you'll be more likely to get useful answers. For today: Clearly, `words_file` is null (`None`).

Comment: The problem isn't with `read_words()`, its with `words_file`

Comment: as a side note, your `fh.close()` is after the `return data`, which is therefore not called.

Comment: @alexis I think the problem is that he didn't know the meaning of the keyword `None`, for a beginner that might not be so clear.

Comment: The error is clear. When you try to do `fh = open(words_file)`, it complains: `TypeError: invalid file: None`. Ergo, `words_file` is `None`

Comment: Thank you all, this is very helpful info and I really appreciate it. @alexis I will also take on board your advice next time re isolating the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the driver program you've linked to, I see these lines calling your read_words function:

```
words_file = askopenfile(mode='r', title='Select word list file')
words = a3.read_words(words_file)
words_file.close()
```

As others have pointed out, what askopenfile is returning is None. I suggest you experiment with this function and determine why this is. I suspect that the filename you're entering isn't where you think it is, and this is why you're not getting a file back.

Furthermore, a little research suggests that askopenfile returns a file handle, not a filename - your code assumes that you're getting a filename (and hence you're opening it), which will also be incorrect.